# What's the translation of “emote" in French?

Tags: traduction, jeux, langage-des-jeunes, internet

An emote [is a](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Emote)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210421203156/https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Emote)):

> A term used in MMORPG's such as World of Warcraft which describes an action your character can perform which is usually accompanied by sound and sometimes even an animation. Emotes include:

E.g.:

[image]

([image source](https://giphy.com/explore/emote-sticker), which contains other examples)

What's the translation of “emote" in French?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=emote&op=translate) didn't help.

Comment: Il semblerait que le français ait conservé le mot anglais. Voir par exemple [ici](https://worldofwarcraft.judgehype.com/generalites_emotes/) ou [là](https://tips.clip-studio.com/fr-fr/articles/3050).  Je pense qu'un non initié dirait simplement [une animation](http://www.ordinateur.cc/Logiciel/Jeux-PC/145914.html).

Comment: @None You could make that an answer honestly. In gaming circles, at least in my experience, a lot of the specific vocabulary is directly borrowed from English. Spawn, emote, kill (as a noun), loot, map, etc.

Comment: @AmiralPatate  In my generation of early adopters of the internet  we just used to call that *gif animé* but I wasn't sure gamers would use that word.  I'm not a gamer and I don't chase upmarks. I just know what you have just said and how to verify things that are easily available online. Feel free to copy paste my comment. No problem.

Comment: @None Thanks! gif animé isn't necessarily an emote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[L'Office québecois de la langue française](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26545314) suggère « émotion animée » et « émote ».

Answer (score 2):

With the emote as you define it in your question (as opposed to an emoji or smiley, which is a different form of emoting), and in a gaming context you will encounter that word directly borrowed from English, either as ***emote*** or sometimes ***émote***. Because it's a non-standard word, the gender of *emote* will be up to the speaker. I would lean towards *une emote* (because *une émotion*, *une animation*), but I've seen and heard *un emote* used before.

If you're looking for an established French word in a more general context, ***animation*** will probably be your best bet, an emote here being a character animation.

Source: personal experience. In general, with multiplayer games pitting you with international players, the English word will usually impose itself as a standard across languages.